# Firefox css float bug with a:link not in IE or Chrome

Tags: asp.net, css, firefox

My default page works fine in ie but Firefox it has problems with the `a:link`.
At my page http://www.printer-ink-toner.co.uk and half way down is a link to my status on ebay.
For Firefox this link does not work and for ie it does. I can reproduce this behavior on my development PC also.

The link is contained in a float div block called "centercol50pct" which has CSS of

```
 .centercol50pct {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 380px;
    margin:0px 5px 0px 0px;
  }
```

If the `float:left;` is removed it works fine. changing any other parameter does not have an effect on the problem.

In addition the search drop downs do not work in Firefox either. I assume it is related but thought I would try and solve the more simple 'a link' problem first

Thanks
Nigel

Comment: Have you got a link available that we can take a look at? Or a version of the code on jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centrecolLowerblock div was covering up the above content, therefore making the link unreachable.

Change

```
#centrecolLowerblock {
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

to

```
#centrecolLowerblock {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Also your dropdowns are not working due to the same problem (an element is overlapping them). Try changing.

```
h3.h3_Largeblue {
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

to

```
h3.h3_Largeblue {
    clear: both;
    color: blue;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

That should sort the problem's :)

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much!!!. What tool did you y=use to see that the h3 div was intervering with the dropdowns?